# Flutter SharedPreferences Error on iOS and macOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-sharedpreference

I am trying to run my Flutter application via Xcode and I keep getting the error

> Warning: Unable to create restoration in progress marker file (11db)

It seems to happen on line 18 of the file 'SharedPreferencesPlugin.swift' (`let messenger = registrar.messenger()`) where it says

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

I am new to Flutter development so I am unsure how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

This will add a line like this to your package's pubspec.yaml (and run an implicit `flutter pub get`):

```
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.1
```

Then, perform the below-mentioned commands one by one.

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
```